# perform select fails to compile postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have some SQL in which I want to test whether a certain record exists.  I initially tried

```
    perform select  from vote,file 
           where vote.file_id=file.file_id and vote.uid = userId and
                 file.basename=aBase[1];
```

with the idea of testing whether the item with given uid and basename was found.  The compiler complained about an error at **select**.  To make it compile I had to declare **version** and write:

```
    select file.basename into version from vote,file ....
```

Can someone explain why the **perform** here failed?  I have other seemingly identical code which works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PostGreSQL DOC, SEE http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html

> **Note:** One might expect that writing SELECT directly would accomplish
>   this result, but at present the only accepted way to do it is PERFORM.
>   A SQL command that can return rows, such as SELECT, will be rejected
>   as an error unless it has an INTO clause.